# Can I declare a global variable and refer to it from anywhere without referring to its class?

Tags: c#, global

I have a C# console app. I'd like the main program to determine if I'm in DEBUG mode, for example, and set a variable, say... g_Bypass which every class can just refer to.

Example:

```
class test
{
    public static bool g_testMode;

    test()
    {
        g_testMode = true;  // read from the database.
        // more code...
        Object1 _obj = new Object1();
        // do more stuff with _obj...
    }
}

class Object1
{

    public Object1()
    {
        // constructor
        if (g_testMode)          // << I'd like to just refer to it this way!
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. You must refer to `test.g_testMode`.

Comment: Why not just use the app.config and store it there, then use transformations for Dev/Test/Debug etc?

Answer (score 2):

No. In .Net every variable and method has to be enclosed in a class. However, a static public member is accessible with global scope, but you have to prefix it with the class name when using it outside of the class. But you could call your class `g`, than instead of `g_testMode` you have to write `g.testMode`. Although lower-case class names are discouraged, maybe better `G.testMode`.

Your example would than read as:

```
static class G //static is not necessary here
{
    public static bool testMode;
}
class test
{
    test()
    {
        G.testMode = true;  // read from the database.
        // more code...
        Object1 _obj = new Object1();
        // do more stuff with _obj...
    }
}

class Object1
{

    public Object1()
    {
        // constructor
        if (G.testMode)          // << I'd like to just refer to it this way!
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is debug mode you are worried about you could create a local variable in a method or a member variable within a class definition by doing the following:

```
#if DEBUG
    bool debug = true;
#else
    bool debug = false;
#endif
```

If for some reason you want to create a global static:

```
public static class Test {
#if DEBUG
    public static bool debug = true;
#else
    public static bool debug = false;
#endif
}
```

This needs to be referenced outside of the object as `Test.debug`

You need to define the variable `DEBUG` in the project's build screen

JUST BECAUSE YOU CAN DO THIS DOESN'T MEAN YOU SHOULD!!!

Comment: I have yet to write a substantial commercial application that didn't have some substantial read-only data structures (or sometimes a collection of such structures.)  There isn't really anything gained by not making such things global.

Comment: @LorenPechtel how about testability? It sucks to have to figure out which bits of the global state need to be set up to run a unit test.